# Jersey REST - multiple file upload and JAXB object

Tags: rest, jersey

I am using Jersey for REST.
For `POST`, can we upload 2 files and send JAXB annotated object as well?

```
@POST
@Path("create")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Override
public Response addData(FormDataMultiPart multiform, System type)
```

Any suggestions please?